# React navigation broken within function call

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm new to react native and I can only seem to find documentation for how to navigate between screens in the return() method for react native.  I'm wondering what the syntax is for navigation in a function call.  The line I am having trouble with is line 37 (in the login function).

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput
} from 'react-native';
import Input from './Input';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import {firebaseApp} from './App';
import {Tabs} from './Router';



export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      status: ''
    }

    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
  }

  login(){
    console.log("Logging in");

    firebaseApp.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error.code);
      console.log(error.message);
    })

    this.props.navigation.navigate('TabNav');

    console.log("Navigate to Home");

  }

  render() {
    var styles = require('./Styles');
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;

    return(
      <View style={styles.loginContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.loginHeader}>PRINCETON EVENTS</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.loginInput}
          placeholder="Email"
          autoCapitalize='none'
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({email: text})}
          value={this.state.email}
          returnKeyType='next'/>
        <TextInput
          secureTextEntry
          style={styles.loginInput} placeholder="Password"
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({password: text})}
          value={this.state.password}
          autoCapitalize='none'
          returnKeyType='go'/>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.loginButton}>
          <Text style={styles.loginText} onPress={this.login}>LOGIN</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.loginButton}
          onPress = {() => navigate('CreateAccount')}>
          <Text style={styles.loginText}> CREATE ACCOUNT </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );

}
}
```

This is Router.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import {StackNavigator, TabNavigator} from 'react-navigation';

import InputScreen from './InputPage';
import HomeScreen from './Home';
import DetailsScreen from './Details';
import MyEventsScreen from './MyEvents';
import EditScreen from './EditPage';
import MapScreen from './Map';
import CreateAccountScreen from './CreateAccount';
import LoginScreen from './Login';

export const MyEventsStack = StackNavigator({

  MyEvents: {
    screen: MyEventsScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  },
  MyEventsDetails: {
    screen: EditScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,

    },
  },

});


export const EventsStack = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    },
  },
  Details: {
    screen: DetailsScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    },
  },
});

export const Tabs = TabNavigator({
  Home: {screen: EventsStack},
  EventMap: {screen: MapScreen},
  Input: {screen: InputScreen},
  MyEvents:{screen: MyEventsStack},
},{
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColors: '#e91e63',
    }
});

export const LoginNav = StackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: LoginScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    },
  },
  CreateAccount: { screen: CreateAccountScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    }
  },
});

/*export const SuccessLoginNav = StackNavigator({
  Main: { screen: Tabs,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    }
  },
});*/



export const Root = StackNavigator({
  TabNav: {
    screen: Tabs,
  }


}, {headerMode: 'none'});
```

Answer (score 2):

In `login`, you're declaring a function but neither invoking it or assigning it to anything:

```
() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
```

Essentially that line does nothing.  Try removing the anonymous function declaration:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Home');
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  I removed the anonymous function declaration.  That was a problem but it still does not navigate like it should.  I added router.js to the original question.  Is there something wrong with my stack navigators?

Comment: What version of React Router are you using?

Comment: I'm confused by the question.  I'm using react native 0.44 and I'm using react-navigation

Comment: React Router (https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) is a specific package...there were a lot of breaking changes between 3.x and 4.x, but a lot of people are still using 3.x, which is why I ask

Comment: If you see `"react-router"` in your `package.json` file, you're using React Router, and you will see the version number there.

Comment: I'm not using 'react-router' I'm using 'react-navigation' if that makes a difference.

Comment: Ah, that does make a difference.  I removed `react-router` from your tags.  I'm afraid I can't help you too much as I've never used `react-navigation`...maybe I'll take a look later.